# groupby on column which contain bytearray object using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have pandas dataframe and want to do groupby on Customer ID

```
 df['rank_col'] = df.groupby('PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID')['DB_CREATED_DT'].rank(method='first')
```

now the problem is pseudo_customer_ID  which look like this

```
 [138, 76, 16, 9, 86, 71, 5, 85, 117, 237, 97, 212, 13, 157, 185, 150, 207, 97, 85, 165]
```

below is snapshot when I did value count on  of pseudo customer ID,

[image]

I check the single value I got below value

[image]

**Note: I want to do groupby on pseudo_customer_ID and do rank by DB_CREATED_DT column**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your `bytearray` with the `bytes` function to allow grouping (and get hashable type):

Demo:

```
df['PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID_BYTES'] = df['PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID'].apply(bytes)
print(df)

# Output:
                                  PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID                           PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID_BYTES
0  [138, 76, 16, 9, 86, 71, 5, 85, 117, 237, 97, ...  b'\x8aL\x10\tVG\x05Uu\xeda\xd4\r\x9d\xb9\x96\x...
```

Group by `PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID`:

```
>>> list(df.groupby('PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID'))
...
TypeError: unhashable type: 'bytearray'
```

Group by `PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID_BYTES`:

```
>>> list(df.groupby('PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID_BYTES'))

[(b'\x8aL\x10\tVG\x05Uu\xeda\xd4\r\x9d\xb9\x96\xcfaU\xa5',
                                    PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID                           PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID_BYTES
  0  [138, 76, 16, 9, 86, 71, 5, 85, 117, 237, 97, ...  b'\x8aL\x10\tVG\x05Uu\xeda\xd4\r\x9d\xb9\x96\x...)]
```

**Important**

If you are sure of your original encoding, you can use `str.decode` to get a `str` instead of a `bytes` string. Here it seems to be `latin-1`:

```
df['PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID_STR'] = df['PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID'].decode('latin1'))
print(df.loc[0])

# Output:
PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID          [138, 76, 16, 9, 86, 71, 5, 85, 117, 237, 97, ...
PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID_BYTES    b'\x8aL\x10\tVG\x05Uu\xeda\xd4\r\x9d\xb9\x96\x...
PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID_STR                                 L\tVGUuíaÔ\rÏaU¥
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Demo:

```
>>> list(df.groupby('PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID_STR'))

[('\x8aL\x10\tVG\x05UuíaÔ\r\x9d¹\x96ÏaU¥',
                                    PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID                           PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID_BYTES  PSEUDO_CUSTOMER_ID_STR
  0  [138, 76, 16, 9, 86, 71, 5, 85, 117, 237, 97, ...  b'\x8aL\x10\tVG\x05Uu\xeda\xd4\r\x9d\xb9\x96\x...  L\tVGUuíaÔ\rÏaU¥)]
```

Comment: I hope I was clear enough and solve your problem.